# Mariadb.service failed because a fatal signal

Tags: mariadb

Suddenly my database has crashed. When I run the command `service mariadb restart`, I got the following error:

> ob for mariadb.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process. See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

After that I ran this code `journalctl -xe` after restarting my server, I am getting this error.

```
[root@mumbai algotradingtoolx]# journalctl -xe
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai mysqld[19463]: The manual page at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-produce-a-full-stack-trace-for-mysqld/ contains
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai mysqld[19463]: information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai mysqld[19463]: Writing a core file...
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai mysqld[19463]: Working directory at /var/lib/mysql
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai mysqld[19463]: Resource Limits:
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai mysqld[19463]: Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai mysqld[19463]: Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai mysqld[19463]: Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai mysqld[19463]: Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai mysqld[19463]: Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai mysqld[19463]: Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai mysqld[19463]: Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai mysqld[19463]: Max processes             29854                29854                processes
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai mysqld[19463]: Max open files            32768                32768                files
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai mysqld[19463]: Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai mysqld[19463]: Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai mysqld[19463]: Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai mysqld[19463]: Max pending signals       29854                29854                signals
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai mysqld[19463]: Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai mysqld[19463]: Max nice priority         0                    0
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai mysqld[19463]: Max realtime priority     0                    0
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai mysqld[19463]: Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai systemd[1]: mariadb.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.2.40 database server.
-- Subject: Unit mariadb.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mariadb.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai systemd[1]: Started Plesk Web Socket Service.
-- Subject: Unit plesk-web-socket.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit plesk-web-socket.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai grafana-server[2048]: t=2021-09-13T13:28:32+0530 lvl=eror msg="Alert Rule Result Error" logger=alerting.evalContext ruleId=3 name="Mail server memory usage" error="request hand
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai grafana-server[2048]: t=2021-09-13T13:28:32+0530 lvl=eror msg="Alert Rule Result Error" logger=alerting.evalContext ruleId=2 name="nginx memory usage" error="request handler re
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai sw-engine-pleskrun[19485]: [2021-09-13 13:28:32.979] 19485:613f04a8eeea8 ERR [panel] DB query failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused:
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai sw-engine-pleskrun[19485]: 0: /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:79
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai sw-engine-pleskrun[19485]: Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(string 'SET sql_mode = ''')
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai sw-engine-pleskrun[19485]: 1: /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/CommonPanel/Application/Abstract.php:103
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai sw-engine-pleskrun[19485]: CommonPanel_Application_Abstract::initDbAdapter()
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai sw-engine-pleskrun[19485]: 2: /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/Session/Helper.php:176
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai sw-engine-pleskrun[19485]: Plesk\Session\Helper::initStorage()
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai sw-engine-pleskrun[19485]: 3: /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/CommonPanel/Application/Abstract.php:52
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai sw-engine-pleskrun[19485]: CommonPanel_Application_Abstract->run()
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai sw-engine-pleskrun[19485]: 4: /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/CommonPanel/Application/Abstract.php:34
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai sw-engine-pleskrun[19485]: CommonPanel_Application_Abstract::init()
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai sw-engine-pleskrun[19485]: 5: /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/pm/Bootstrap.php:16
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai sw-engine-pleskrun[19485]: pm_Bootstrap::init()
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai sw-engine-pleskrun[19485]: 6: /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/sdk.php:11
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai sw-engine-pleskrun[19485]: require_once(string '/usr/local/psa/admin/plib/sdk.php')
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai sw-engine-pleskrun[19485]: 7: /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/WebSocket/bin/ws-server.php:3
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai sw-engine-pleskrun[19485]: ERROR: Plesk\Exception\Database: DB query failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (Mysql.php:79)
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai systemd[1]: plesk-web-socket.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai systemd[1]: Unit plesk-web-socket.service entered failed state.
Sep 13 13:28:32 mumbai systemd[1]: plesk-web-socket.service failed.
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: 1) This question is about database admin problem, not about programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. The DBA sister site of SO provides help with such questions. 2) Before reporsting the question ont the DBA site, please check out mariadb's error log to see what caused the issue. The log you attached simply informs us that mariadb has crashed, but contains no clue as to why.

Comment: Hi, MariaDB-10.2.40 is still a supported version. Put in a [bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org/). If you include some SQL that generated the crash, and some table information, this might be enough to get the bug fixed for next release. Please see [MariaDB Community Bug Reporting](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-community-bug-reporting/). I look forward to seeing your bug report.